# How to melt a 3D data frame to the long format

Tags: r

I have a text file containing data that looks like this:

```
#    time;   allPop;  allPop;  allPop; ions1; ions1; ions1; elec1; elec1; elec1; 
#        ;   allNodes;  node0;  node1;  allNodes;  node0;  node1;  allNodes;  node0;  node1; 
0.011082077;-330.84293;-5.28E-04;-0.008617032;2.39E-12;9.94E-13;1.29E-12;-331.09302;-0.015284455;-0.013646739; 
0.011132077;-332.19788;1.17E-04;-0.004885694;2.76E-12;9.99E-13;1.30E-12;-332.44925;-0.014786674;-0.009936244; 
0.011182077;-330.7951;2.05E-04;-0.003262551;3.10E-12;9.98E-13;1.27E-12;-331.0478;-0.015050205;-0.00879398; 
0.011232077;-331.62976;0.001411756;-0.001674229;3.35E-12;9.85E-13;1.28E-12;-331.88593;-0.015500192;-0.008433639; 
0.011282077;-333.03204;-8.67E-04;-0.001743055;3.54E-12;9.81E-13;1.29E-12;-333.28497;-0.01616466;-0.009426347; 
0.011332078;-330.76794;-0.001515289;-0.001287116;3.66E-12;9.86E-13;1.31E-12;-331.01965;-0.015228378;-0.008569364; 
0.011382078;-331.39044;0.002540908;-5.25E-04;3.71E-12;9.92E-13;1.32E-12;-331.6468;-0.014409032;-0.008052639; 
0.011432078;-330.43414;-0.001792867;-2.51E-04;3.68E-12;9.60E-13;1.32E-12;-330.68936;-0.01623829;-0.008444168; 
0.011482078;-330.86917;4.81E-04;1.41E-04;3.70E-12;9.76E-13;1.33E-12;-331.12268;-0.014885588;-0.009113268; 
0.011532078;-330.33435;6.66E-04;-1.58E-04;3.72E-12;9.79E-13;1.33E-12;-330.58813;-0.015093705;-0.009414361; 
0.011582078;-330.7523;-7.40E-04;-0.001010344;3.70E-12;9.66E-13;1.32E-12;-331.00278;-0.015855879;-0.009049743; 
0.011632077;-329.58597;2.41E-04;-1.02E-04;3.71E-12;9.67E-13;1.32E-12;-329.83893;-0.015224142;-0.008584219; 
0.011682077;-331.54898;-0.001295898;0.001874733;3.71E-12;9.69E-13;1.31E-12;-331.80432;-0.015666598;-0.008926244;
```

So, as a function of time, I have different populations that are associated with different nodes.
allPop is the sum of all populations on a given node while allNodes is the sum of a given population on all nodes.

The file above is truncated for the sake of readability, which explains why the sums don't match in this example.

Now, I need to store this data in a data frame in the long format, to be able to easily plot it with ggplot2.

Reading the two-line header can be done with:

```
header <- readLines(text.connection, n = 2)
header <- gsub("#", "", header)
header <- gsub(" ", "", header)
header <- strsplit(header, ",")
```

Reading the data can be done with:

```
data.vs.time <- read.csv(text.connection, header = FALSE, skip = 2)
```

Now what I want to do is to melt (from reshape2) this data frame in the long format.

My first idea is the following:

```
colnames(data.vs.time) <- paste(header[[1]], header[[2]], sep = "/")
colnames(data.vs.time)[[1]] <- "time"

data.vs.time.molten <- melt(data.vs.time, id.vars = "time")
```

Which gives me something like that:

```
           time           variable         value
1    0.01000000    allPop/allNodes -2.927736e-13
2    0.01000000    allPop/allNodes -6.097465e+02
3    0.01000000    allPop/allNodes -5.440071e+02
4    0.01000000    allPop/allNodes -5.120425e+02
5    0.01000000    allPop/allNodes -4.633145e+02
6    0.01000000    allPop/allNodes -4.168849e+02
[...]
```

Well, I can plot it with:

```
ggplot(data.vs.time.molten, aes(time, value, color = variable)) + geom_line()
```

And it works, but it's not really readable. Too many curves, not enough colors available.

And if I only want to display data on one node or from one population, I have to do something like:

```
ggplot(data.vs.time.molten[grepl("node0", as.character(data.vs.time.molten$variable)), ], aes(time, value, color = variable)) + geom_line()
```

But the legend is redundant then.

Is there a better way to do it?

I was thinking about obtaining a data frame with 4 columns: time, node, pop, value, but don't know how to have it.

Is there a good solution to plot the curves in a readable way? In real life, I have 36 levels for the "variable" column. Plotting them all in one graph is not helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed your steps with your example data and I've got a dataframe with 117 rows that looks like this:

```
> head(data.vs.time.long)
        time        variable     value
1 0.01108208 allPop/allNodes -330.8429
2 0.01113208 allPop/allNodes -332.1979
3 0.01118208 allPop/allNodes -330.7951
4 0.01123208 allPop/allNodes -331.6298
5 0.01128208 allPop/allNodes -333.0320
```

Maybe you can get what you want by splitting your `variable` column (either with `reshape2` or `tidyr`  and using facets to split up your visualization a little.

Start by splitting the column:

```
dvt.separate <- data.vs.time.long %>% 
  separate(variable, into = c("pop", "nodes"), sep = '/')
```

Which gives you this output with the `variable` column split into separate `pop` and `nodes` variables:

```
> head(dvt.separate)
        time    pop    nodes     value
1 0.01108208 allPop allNodes -330.8429
2 0.01113208 allPop allNodes -332.1979
3 0.01118208 allPop allNodes -330.7951
4 0.01123208 allPop allNodes -331.6298
5 0.01128208 allPop allNodes -333.0320
```

Then, plot with `facet_wrap` (note that I've taken the log of the absolute value to show that the plot is working):

```
ggplot(dvt.separate,
       aes(x = time, y = log(abs(value)))) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = nodes)) + 
  facet_wrap(facets = ~ pop)
```

Outputs something like:

[image]

Additionally, you can now more easily filter for a specific node:

```
filter(dvt.separate, nodes == "node1") %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x = time, y = value, color = pop)) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Libraries:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
```